# Jquery UI Layout - Resize while resizing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-layout

in this example http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/toggle_alternate_layouts.html 
you can see that the resize is "on the fly".

I think it is the option "resizeWhileDragging:  true" but it dont work in my example
-> http://jsfiddle.net/FrbW8/28/

My Problem is that i cant find any documentation about his (myabe i am too blind :) )
-> http://layout.jquery-dev.net/documentation.cfm

I hope somebody can help me.
kind regards
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resizeWhileDragging feature is not implemented in version 1.2.0 of jquery.layout, but is in 1.3.0.

replace this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://layout.jquery-dev.net//lib/js/jquery.layout-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

with this:

```
< script type="text/javascript" src="http://layout.jquery-dev.net/lib/js/jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>
```

And you have the newest version of jquery.layout (1.3.0)

Comment: "but is in 1.3.0" ... argh. 
Thank you!